# Java and Telnet resposnse unreadble

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I´m trying to connection using telnet, but the response of server it´s a unreadble string, can some one help me? ( the telnet server is a windows XP), I want to authenticate by telnet and execute some commands.
the following code bellow

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TelnetClient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    // Create object of Socket
    Socket soc = new Socket("192.168.56.101", 23);
    String Command;
    // Create object of Input Stream to read from socket
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
    // Create object of Output Stream to write on socket
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
    // Object of Buffered Reader to read command from terminal
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Welcome to Telnet Client");
    System.out.println("< Telnet Prompt >");
    Command = br.readLine();// reads the command
    dout.writeUTF(Command);// sends command to server
    System.out.println(din.readLine()); // gets the response of server
    soc.close(); // close port
    din.close(); // close input stream
    dout.close(); // close output stream
    br.close(); // close buffered Reader
}

}
```

and the response of server is : ÿý%ÿûÿûÿý'ÿýÿý with a lot of "?"

Answer (score 1):

Telnet isn't just a "connect and go" protocol, you'll have to do some basic handshaking and negotiate options upon connection to - for example - be able to transfer 8-bit data. What you're seeing is the server's attempt at negotiating connection options.

The base protocol - including how negotiation is done - is described in [rfc854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) and [there are a bunch of RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs) describing the options you could negotiate. In short, you'll need to do some basic negotiation with the server upon connect (at least denying all option requests) to get to the real data.

Comment: @user1763778 In Java, I've used [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) for telnet before, it does all the hard parts for you, although you still have control over all options you want to actually use (such as 8-bit clean data).

Comment: +1 I would add that as Telnet contains a binary protocol with `0xff` being highly significant, you should use an `InputStream`, not a `Reader.`